# How to place filtered values into dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my React web application, I'm trying to implement a feature where selecting a Province filters the options in the City dropdown to only display cities belonging to that Province. However, there's an issue where upon selecting a Province, the City dropdown automatically scrolls to the first city listed under that Province, while still displaying all cities from other Provinces.

I'm trying to only display the cities that belong to a province when selected, not show all provinces.

I tried filtering/mapping over the `filteredData`, and then setting the cityDropdownFilter state to `filteredCities[0]` (so it would only show the filtered cities from the selected province and nothing else), but that's not working.

Here's the snippet of code where I'm trying to implement the logic, which lives inside of my "Header.tsx" component:

```
const handleDropdownFilterProvince = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>
  ) => {
    useFilterStore.setState({ provinceDropdownFilter: e.target.value });

    // Filter the data based on the selected province
    const filteredCitiesSet = new Set<string>(
      filteredData
        .filter((item) => item.state === e.target.value)
        .map((item) => item.city)
    );

    const filteredCities = Array.from(filteredCitiesSet);

    useFilterStore.setState({ cityDropdownFilter: filteredCities[0] });
    console.log("handle province dropdown cities", filteredCities);

    // Clear out other cities from dropdown that don't match selected province
    // ^^^ need to figure out logic here
  };
```

For context, here's the full code below of the Header component:

**Header.tsx:**

```
export const Header = ({ data, isLoading, error }: HeaderProps) => {
 
  ...
  // Bring in global state
  const {
    manufacturerDropdownFilter,
    provinceDropdownFilter,
    cityDropdownFilter,
    priceRangeFilter,
  } = useFilterStore();

  const filteredData = data.map((group) => group.equipments).flat();

  ...

  const handleDropdownFilterProvince = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>
  ) => {
    useFilterStore.setState({ provinceDropdownFilter: e.target.value });

    // Filter the data based on the selected province
    const filteredCitiesSet = new Set<string>(
      filteredData
        .filter((item) => item.state === e.target.value)
        .map((item) => item.city)
    );

    const filteredCities = Array.from(filteredCitiesSet);

    useFilterStore.setState({ cityDropdownFilter: filteredCities[0] });
    console.log("handle province dropdown cities", filteredCities);

    // Clear out other cities from dropdown that don't match selected province
    // ^^^ need to figure out logic here
  };

  const handleDropdownFilterCity = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>
  ) => {
    useFilterStore.setState({ cityDropdownFilter: e.target.value });
  };

  ...

  return (
    <>
    ...
          <Dropdown
            data={filteredData}
            value={provinceDropdownFilter}
            onChange={handleDropdownFilterProvince}
            filterType="state"
          />
          <Dropdown
            data={filteredData}
            value={cityDropdownFilter}
            onChange={handleDropdownFilterCity}
            filterType="city"
          />
    ...
    </>
  );
};
```

And full code for the Dropdown component:

**Dropdown.tsx:**

```
export const Dropdown: React.FC<DropdownProps> = ({
  data,
  onChange,
  value,
  filterType,
}) => {
  
  ...

  // Filter the data based on the filterType
  const filteredOptions = data.filter((i) => {
    if (filterType === "manufacturer") {
      return i.manufacturer;
    }
    if (filterType === "state") {
      return i.state;
    }
    if (filterType === "city") {
      return i.city;
    }

    return false;
  });

  // Remove duplicate values to show each value only once (e.g., "TX", "Los Angeles") instead of fetching every instance from the API.
  const uniqueValues = new Set<string>();

  for (let i = 0; i < filteredOptions.length; i++) {
    uniqueValues.add(filteredOptions[i][filterType] as string);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Select
        aria-label="Select"
        placeholder={getCustomPlaceholder(filterType) as string}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleFilters}
      >
        {Array.from(uniqueValues)
          .sort()
          .map((value) => (
            <option key={value} value={value}>
              {value}
            </option>
          ))}
      </Select>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: You comment the useFilterStore with "bring in global state", but from the naming convention it sounds as if it is a custom hook that does not alter the global state but returns the original state on every render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

`cityDropdownFilter` is being used as the dropdown value `value={cityDropdownFilter}"` then you are setting the dropdown value based on a different set of cities to what is in the dropdown data.

```js
        <Dropdown
            data={filteredData}
            value={cityDropdownFilter}
            onChange={handleDropdownFilterCity}
            filterType="city"
          />
```

### The solution

Filter the dropdown `data` instead:

```js
      <Dropdown
            data={filteredData.filter((item) => item.state === provinceDropdownFilter)}
            value={cityDropdownFilter}
            onChange={handleDropdownFilterCity}
            filterType="city"
          />
```

Comment: Oh my gosh I need to give you a giant hug. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Side note - since the data for the city dropdown is now filtered based on the province, on load the city dropdown values are blank because no province has yet been selected. Is there a way to, on load, load all provinces by default?

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it! Updated code with loading all province values by default before a user selects a Province: ` <Dropdown
            data={
              provinceDropdownFilter
                ? filteredData.filter(
                    (item) => item.state === provinceDropdownFilter
                  )
                : filteredData
            }
            value={cityDropdownFilter}
            onChange={handleDropdownFilterCity}
            filterType="city"
          />`

Comment: Optimisation suggestion: could be worth putting that in a `useMemo` and only recalculating it when `provinceDropdownFilter` changes.